# Working with AlamoFire and local JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

I realise this sounds a bit counter intuitive but I need to work with a local JSON file while our REST api is being built. I'm also using SwiftyJson to parse it and I had this working in a very rudimentary way, I am now wanting to expand a bit on thee basics and start to flesh out some of the proper requests etc. so, in effect all I will have to do is swap the local JSON path for the HTTP one when its ready.

I appreciate this is probably a little noobish but I couldnt find any documentation on this particular scenario :\

My current attempts are below:

Job.swift:

```
class func endpointForjob() -> String {
        DataManager.getJobsDataFromLocalFile { (data) -> Void in
             // Get jobs from local jobs.json file (dummy data while we work on the networking)

            let jsonData = JSON(data: data)

        }
        return jsonData //i know this wont work, just giving an idea of how i *think* this should work
       //        return "http://ourUrl.co/api/v1/job/"

    }
```

DataManager.swift:

```
 class func getJobsDataFromLocalFile(success: ((data: NSData) -> Void)) {
    //1
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
      //2
      let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("jobs",ofType:"json")

      var readError:NSError?
      if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile:filePath!,
        options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingUncached,
        error:&readError) {
        success(data: data)
      }
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and rather obvious solution is to just serve the JSON file from your localhost

```
class func endpointForjob() -> String {
       return "http://localhost/jsonfile.json"
    }
```